# Extracting dates from string

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I have a list with file names that look roughly like this: Gadget1-010912000000-020912235959.csv, i.e. they contain two dates indicating the timespan of their data.

The user enters a date format and a file format:

- File Format in this case: *GADGET*-*DATE_FROM*-*DATE_TO*.csv
- Date format in this case: ddMMyyHHmmss

What I want to do is extracting the three values out of the file name with the given file and date format.

My problem is: Since the date format can differ heavily (hours, minutes and seconds can be seperated by a colon, dates by a dot,...) I don't quite know how to create a fitting regular expression.

Comment: If the original date format is not fixed, it is going to be difficult and error prone.

Comment: Can you give more examples of the date format? Best if it covers all the cases you have.

Comment: You need to normalise all the variations into a common format. Only you know what all the variations are and how to transform them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove non digits characters, and then parse value.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");

String[] fileNameDetails = ("Gadget1-010912000000-020912235959").split("-");

/*Catch All non digit characters and removes it. If non exists maintains original string*/
String date = fileNameDetails[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

try{
    dateFormat.parse(fileNameDetails[1]);
}catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**SimpleDateFormat** solves your issue. You can define the format with commas, spaces and whatever and simply parse according to the format:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

So you map your format (e.g ddMMyyHHmmss) to a corresponding SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");
Date x = format.parse("010912000000");
```

If the format changes, you simply change the SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of date-time formats, trying each until one works.

You may need to order the formats to prioritize matches.

For example, with Joda time, you can use [DateTimeFormat.forPattern()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29) and [DateTimeFormatter.getParser()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#getParser%28%29) for each of a series of patterns. Try [DateTimeParser.parseInto()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParser.html#parseInto%28org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) until one succeeds.

One nice thing about this approach is that it is easy to add and remove patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` class.

Look at the example:

```
String inputDate = "01.09.12.00:00:00";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
  "([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[:]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[:]{0,1}([0-9]{2})");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputDate);
  matcher.find();
  StringBuilder cleanStr = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    cleanStr.append(matcher.group(i));
  } 
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");
  Date x = format.parse(cleanStr.toString());
  System.out.println(x.toString());
```

The most important part is line

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
  "([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[\\.]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[:]{0,1}([0-9]{2})[:]{0,1}([0-9]
```

Here you define regexp and mark groups in paranthesis so `([0-9]{2})` marks a group. Then is expression for possible delimeters `[\\.]*` in this case 0 or 1 dot, but you can put more possible delimeters for example `[\\.|\]{0,1}`.

Then you run `matcher.find()` which returns true if pattern matches. And then using `matcher.group(int)` you can get group by group. Note that index of first group is 1.

Then I construct clean date `String` using `StringBuilder`. And then parse date.

Cheers,
Michal